# On a property of measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

One well know property of Lebesgue Outer Measure is the following:

$$(P1) \text{ Let } A \subseteq \mathbb{R}. \text{ Then for any } \epsilon > 0 \text{ there exists an open set } \mathcal{O}_{\epsilon}, \text{ such that},\\ 
A \subseteq \mathcal{O}_{\epsilon} \text{ and } m^*(\mathcal{O}_{\epsilon}) \leq m^*(A) + \epsilon.$$

I am wondering if there is a similar property for a closed set. In other words, something like the following:

$$(P2) \text{ Let } A \subseteq \mathbb{R}. \text{ Then for any } \epsilon > 0 \text{ there exists an closed set } F_{\epsilon}, \text{ such that}, "\quad \quad \quad \quad ".$$

Answer (score 0):

An open set in $\Bbb R$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals (the union of two intersecting interval is an interval, and every open interval contains a rational).

So its closure adds only countably many points, hence its measure is the same.